# Java index out of bounds exception index:2, Size:2

Tags: java, list, for-loop

here is the error that I am getting. If you need more information regarding the full code let me know.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at main.Field.upCountFirst(Field.java:158)
    at main.Field$1.actionPerformed(Field.java:55)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my Code and I don't get what is wrong with it i+1 should not be out of bounds...(Not very good at programming so I don't quite see the problem through.)

```
list.add(x);
String temp = x;
for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i) + " X" + list.size());
    if(list.size() >= 2) {
        temp = temp + list.get(i+1);
    }
}
System.out.println(temp);
```

Comment: For list of size `2`, when `i = 1`, `list.get(2)` is out of bounds. Indexes start from `0`

Comment: Lists (and arrays) are zero-based. So a list's largest index is `1` when its size is `2`.

Comment: Okay Thanks. I confused .size() since that does not start at zero with the index.. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see on the first line of errors: Index: 2, Size: 2

```
if(list.size() >= 2) {
    temp = temp + list.get(i+1);
}
```

So here at the condition is met, because the list size is 2.

`temp = temp + list.get(i+1);` --> here is the problem.

You're saying: get(i+1) which is equal to 2, but the index is actually 1.
First iteration = `i+1 => 0+1 = 1`
Second iteration = `i+1 => 1+1 = 2` ---> this is where you're getting out of bound.

Answer (score 1):

In java arrays and lists start at index `0` and end at index `size - 1`. So if in your loop is `i = 1` then `list.get(i + 1)` will cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, because you are trying to access index `2` which does not exist.